# Downloading a zip file using a JS POST

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to save a zip file received in the response to a POST.  However when it is saved it is not a valid zip file.  I know it is on the server due to saving it inline; obviously the two files are different.  The client side one is larger, but beyond that I'm stumped.  Can anyone spot my error?

On my python - tornado server I have this:

```
zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w')
zf.writestr("TEST.txt", "This is a test string")
zf.close()

self.set_header("Content-Type", 'application/x-zip-compressed')
self.set_header("Content-Disposition", f"attachment; filename=output.zip")
zip_content = zip_buffer.getvalue()
with open("delme.zip", "wb") as out_f:
    out_f.write(zip_content)
self.write(zip_content)
```

On the client in Javascript (using oldschool AngularJS, but I don't think that matters):

```
$http.post(`/web/abstraction_ds/generate`, data=data).then(function(response) {
  let fileAsBlob = new Blob([response.data], {type:'application/x-zip-compressed'});
  let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = `myzip.zip`;
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileAsBlob);
  downloadLink.onclick = function(event) {
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
  }
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  downloadLink.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
})
```

Thanks

Update:  The screenshot shows a HEX dump of the two files.  The file on the left works, the one on the right doesn't:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of each file in a text editor, to see how they are different?

Comment: I have, the client version is slightly larger.  Being binary it is rather hard to work out any significant difference.  But in a text editor they look remarkably similar; both start with "PK", it is an uncompressed zip so I can even see the content of the file in both.  But the client version won't open.

Comment: Can you diff the files? I know they're binary but I'm guessing the difference will highlight the bug. Like maybe some HTML crept in there, or HTTP headers

Comment: The files are pretty short; I've posted a HEX dump of them onto the original question.  Thanks for helping.  I certainly can't see anything smoking in them

Comment: What is is `self.write` doing? And what is your platform (operating system)?

Comment: It could be that what you're seeing is the gzipped version of the file. I think tornado is compressing the file again before sending it. Do you have settings `compress_response` or `GZip` set? (see [the source](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/b3c63fbce0e97fd0428199ffdeddbcb237ef03e9/tornado/web.py#L2033))